# How to set the application to fullscreen from an Intent, Not from the main activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

My Application Has 4 Tabs, Each tab creates a subview ( intent ) now I have a handler for options/menu button within each intent , of the menu items is "Toggle Fullscreen" this doesn't work as the intent isn't the parent view while the activity containing the TabHost is the parent View, Now I need to know how do I Set the whole app. to FullScreen mode or how to Refer to the Parent Activity to Set the full screen mode through it.

Here's a snippet of my code

```
    public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

    public void toggleFullScreen(){
    // This has the code to set App. to full screen
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MywebviewActivity.class);
        tabHost.addTab(             
                tabHost.newTabSpec("SomeName")
                .setIndicator("Some Title")
                .setContent( myIntents ));
```

Now I need to set fullscreen mode from "MywebviewActivity" not from my MainActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify code in your `MainActivity` as following

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MywebviewActivity.class);

 intent.putExtra("isFullScreen", true);
```

now in `onCreate()` method of `MywebviewActivity` write code as following

**put "setContentView(R.layout.main);" method below of this code as following :**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent=getIntent();
    boolean isfullScreen =  intent.getBooleanExtra("isFullScreen", false);


        if(isfullScreen )
        {
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }

setContentView(R.layout.main);


}
```

not it will work

Comment: It doesn't work I even tried to force it to full screen but it didn't work seems like getWindow() in the Intent doesn't get the main window of the whole app.

Comment: I have edited my post. put `setContentView(R.layout.main);` below of full screen code.

Answer (score 0):

check this

add this in your webview activity

```
    Intent i=getIntent();
    if(i!=null)
    {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
```